# create multiple json array from sql

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I have data in my sql which looks somewhat similar to

```
date        system                 Hits
2014-11-11  abc                      1
2014-11-12  abc                      9
2014-11-13  abc                      4
2014-11-14  abc                      7
2014-11-16  abc                      1
2014-11-17  abc                      15
2014-11-18  abc                      9
2014-11-11  two                      27
2014-11-12  two                     66
2014-11-13  two                     96
2014-11-14  two                     68
2014-11-15  two                     10
2014-11-16  two                     14
2014-11-17  two                     119
```

I am able to read them and create a single json array , but my requirement is to make multiple json array based on the computer name

the end result being

```
 var abc = [
                 { Hits: 30 },
                 { Hits: 25 },
                 { Hits: 30 },
                 { Hits: 35 },
                 { Hits: 20 },
                 { Hits: 30 },
                 { Hits: 60 }
            ];
    var two =  [
                 { Hits:  27},
                 { Hits:  66},
                 { Hits:  96},
                 { Hits:  68},
                 { Hits:  10},
                 { Hits:  14},
                 { Hits:  119}
            ];
```

similar for even the date , how do i dynamically create different arrays and populate them accordingly to system name in C#
I am using asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by following steps,

First use "ORDER BY" in your query - It will make the values as organized and now you have sorted result set.

select date, system, Hits from YOUR_TABLE order by COLUMN_YOU_WANT;

Loop through your result set. construct JSON using following trick.

```
String lastValue = "";
bool first = true;
Array YourArray[]; //If you want you can have n number of array for n columns.
while(RESULT NOT END)
{
   /*  //If your prev ORDER BY value differ with current then next value is reached so we need to add old array to JSON and create new array fro new value */
   if(COLUMN_YOU_WANT.value != lastValue && !first) 
   {
       Add Array to JSON and clear Array
   }
   first = false;
   Add the current value to array
}
```

Now your desire JSON will be the end result.

Comment: Then you can use the while loop alone to achieve the desire result.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a rather different approach   Dictionary> for storing and then parsing them in javascript .